# Jupyter Notebook does not start Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Tried all suggested solutions to start Jupyter Notebook from Win 10 (v. 1803) but no success:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

and then edited the file to:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'open -a "Google Chrome" %s'
```

Also set up Chrome as a default browser. Desabled all antiviruses and pop-up blockers

Still I only get:

```
copy and paste one of these URLs:
    http://localhost:8888/?token=5fd225a5087b52cfe92b77bc3b74ba539c2f9058b928c283
```

and after this I get:

```
http://localhost:8888/tree
```

and a blank page below

Interestingly enough in Safari (using Mac) there are no issues to starting Jupyter notebook. Seems only Windows' problem

Anaconda does not start either (from the icon as well). And this is a brand new install

Please, help

PS. there was an attempt to fix this issue (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4303) but I do not think it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there were multiple issues that have prevented Notebook from starting. Not necessarily in the order of importance:

1. Clean up cache in your browser
2. Install node.JS  and upgrade to the latest version

   pip install nodejs
3. Install npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp0) and upgrade to the latest version (https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-install-and-use-node-js-and-npm-mac-and-windows/)

Also seems that the latest version of Notebook has issues since December 2018. Thus:

```
pip uninstall notebook
pip install notebook==5.7.5
```

for me v 5.7.5 instead of 5.7.6 is working but you may need to go lower to 5.6.x

Again, this is only Win 10 issue. Mac OS works fine

Answer (score -1):

Install Anaconda and
Follow  Instruction Carefully
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XScz6tjNSg8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).